# Why is recombination rate in an intrinsic semiconductor proportional to product of number of mobile electrons and number of holes?

Tags: semiconductors

I know that when an electron falls into a hole the number of mobile carriers reduces to zero from two. And when an electron jumps into conduction band the number of mobile carriers increases to two from zero.

But I cannot understand why recombination rate is proportional to the product of holes and conducting/mobile electrons. Does understanding this requires so much complicated math. I know basic probability but is this possible to explain this in high school level? How does the product of those is related to rate?

Comment: For the same reason that a chemical reaction happens at a rate proportional to the product of the concentrations of the reactants. Because it takes one of each reactant interacting with each other for the reaction to happen.

Comment: @ThePhoton Lets say we have 10 X atoms and 10 Y atoms and we push them into a closed tube. And lets assume one X and one Y makes one XY molecule. So we would observe 10 XY molecules at the end from 10 X and 10 Y atoms. Where is the square or product here? This is where Im stuck at.

Comment: The reaction rate doesn't measure how many product molecules you get at the end. It measures how fast you produce the product. If you put 1,000 X and 1,000 Y in, you'd get your 10 product XY molecules much more quickly than if you only put 10 X and 10 Y in and they all had to find each other to react before you could get your 10 XY product molecules.

Comment: Make it extreme: you have a million electrons and NO holes. How many recombinations do you get....

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks I now understand what is meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this from the perspective of the electron:

Assume you have an electron at some point in a semiconductor. Now, you also need a hole in the vicinity. The probability of a hole is proportional to the overall number of holes.

Now, taking a step back, you'll need an electron first – and the probability of having a hole at a certain point is again proportional to the overall number of electrons.

So, it needs "luck" twice, getting an electron in a certain point, then getting a hole in the same. (the order doesn't actually matter – you need both.)

So, make an analogous experiment: Flip a coin (probability of say head=1/2) to figure out whether you get an electron, and roll a die to figure out whether you get a hole (probability of a say ⚅ = 1/6). What's the probability that you get an electron (head) and a hole (⚅) at the same time?

It's the product of these two probabilities, because both events are independent from each other.